# Is there any meaningful difference between event.getParam("x") and event.getParams().x?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events

Why does `getParam()` exist if there is already `getParams()`? Is it only for personal preference?

Should I pick one in certain situations and the other in other situations?

E.g. if `event.getParams().type` looks better to me than `event.getParam("type")`, can I completely forget about the `getParam()` method and always use `getParams()`, without fear of ever doing something in a sub-optimal way?

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference between the two, aside from "intent". If you just need one parameter, getParam is a bit more obvious, but if you need many parameters, getParams() offers an object you can use directly.